# Python: player input using for loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am trying to make a guessing game in python 3 using jupyter notebook whereby two people take turns to guess a number between 1 and 10. What I don't want is that the answer is immediately given like this:

```
from random import randint
rand_num = randint(1,10)

players = ['player_1', 'player_2']

for player in players:
    player_input = int(input('What is your guess {}? '.format(player)))
    if player_input == rand_num:
        print('You won!')
    else:
        print('You lost!')

print('The random number was: {}'.format(rand_num))
```

Instead I want everyone to guess and then the answer is given so that everyone has a fair chance at guessing the number. I tried the following here but this doesn't seem to work because I think the player_input doesn't account for every single player. So when one player got the number right, python prints that every player got the number right.

```
from random import randint
rand_num = randint(1,10)

players = ['player_1', 'player_2']

for player in players:
    player_input = int(input('What is your guess {}? '.format(player)))

for player in players:
    if player_input == rand_num:
        print('You won {}!'.format(player))
    else:
        print('You lost {}!'.format(player))

print('The random number was: {}'.format(rand_num))
```

How can I make this work using lists and for loops?

Answer (score 2):

Loops are probably not suitable for what you want to achieve, you better go with simple case selection by storing the answers of both players:

```
from random import randint
rand_num = randint(1,10)

players = ['player_1', 'player_2']

player_inputs = []
for player in players:
    player_input = int(input('What is your guess {}? '.format(player)))
    player_inputs.append(player_input)

if rand_num in player_inputs:
    if player_inputs[0] == player_inputs[1]:
        print('You both won!')
    elif player_inputs[0] == rand_num:
        print('You won {}!'.format(players[0]))
        print('You lost {}!'.format(players[1]))
    elif player_inputs[1] == rand_num:
        print('You won {}!'.format(players[1]))
        print('You lost {}!'.format(players[0]))
else:
    print('You both lost')

print('The random number was: {}'.format(rand_num))
```